# How to override spacemacs package to use new ELPA version instead of pinned version

Tags: spacemacs, package-repositories

I'd like to use csv-mode 1.7 from ELPA, but spacemacs (develop branch) wants to use the pinned version `spacemacs/.cache/stable-elpa/25.1.1/spacelpa-0.300/csv-mode-1.6.el` (even if I delete that file and/or replace it with 1.7).

What's a nice way to force it to use the latest ELPA version (1.7)?